# How do you copy a directory that has a variable in a path to a designated destination with a standard path

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup, cron

I'd like to automate the following. A bunch of stuff in a folder called `~/Backup/28_10_2019_files/LoadsofStuff` needs to be copied to a folder called `~/Backup/Daily/LoadsofStuff` on a daily basis.

Since the source folder path contains a date syntax it will change every day, the example being today's folder but tomorrow the path will be `~/Backup/29_10_2019_files/LoadsofStuff` and so on.

This syntax sadly is forced by the application generating the backup and it's breaking my copy cronjob.

Is there a way to make sure a cronjob can copy the folder with overwriting to set destination folder, while the source path is different everyday? How would I need to set up a cronjob so that it automatically understands that the source folder path is changing? I would only like to have 1 recent copy of `LoadsofStuff` in the Daily folder.

Thank you for your time and effort,
Ruben

Comment: For the folder, use something like `~/"Backup/$(date +%d_%m_%Y)_files"` and run the `rsync` or whatever you use for the copy via `bash -c ...` so that bash will expand the `$(date ...)` and `~`. Also note that the percent sign has to be escaped in cron jobs!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you can use.

```
34 23 * * * /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/rsync -aH --delete ~/"Backup/$(date +\%d_\%m_\%Y)_files/LoadsofStuff/" ~/"Backup/Daily/LoadsofStuff"'
```

The first 5 columns specify when the job will run: hour, minute, etc. in your local time zone. It's 11:34 PM in the example above. For details on these 5 columns, see section 5 of [Crontab – Quick Reference](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference). After the 5 columns is the command to run.

To configure cron jobs, type `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` (or `vi` in pleace of `nano` if you prefer) and add the above line (all on one line) to the file. To list current jobs, type `crontab -l`.

The example will overwrite and delete files in `~/Backup/Daily/LoadsofStuff` each day. I just want to be sure this is what you want.

Note the `/` at the end of the source folder. This tells rsync to copy everything *inside* of the `LoadsofStuff` folder to the target folder.

On each run, bash will run `date` and replace `$(date +%d_%m_%Y)` with the output. The backslash before each percent sign is something `crontab` requires.